# Fast data structures in Haskell

Tags: haskell, containers, ghc

I have found that in `containers` package crucial data structures such as `Data.Map` or `Data.IntMap` are implemented in pure Haskell.
Question: I wonder, wouldn't it be more efficient to implement them in `C`? I know ghc is very good but definitely cannot compete with optimized `C` code.

Comment: Make sure you're comparing equals with equals; you have to compare Haskell data structures with true C equivalents. First, this means the C code cannot expose in-place mutation to clients of the types. Second, the C code is going to need a memory management story.

Comment: @sacundim I think the question is really, would it be more efficient to use a C implementation via FFI? So that would mean state/memory issues would have to be solved to the same degree as they are in the Haskell implementation.

Comment: Perhaps impure data structures written in C with copy-on-write semantics and refcounting would lead to better performance... It's definitely worth researching.

Comment: @dflemstr: But that would likely carry the extra cost of fantastic amounts of added complexity. In the real world, that's not something that can be brushed aside either. (And if we're not considering real world stuff, `Data.Map` is good enough for everything you want, end of story.)

Comment: Also #Martin, you might consider rephrasing to make this "more of a question", because it's a good question, but it should be made more concrete.

Comment: In general, perhaps, but still, [you'd be surprised what you can pull off, performance-wise.](http://donsbot.wordpress.com/2008/06/04/haskell-as-fast-as-c-working-at-a-high-altitude-for-low-level-performance/)  Obviously, your code isn't going to be quite as idiomatic, but you can do that for library code, since it's behind the scenes.  GHC is a pretty remarkable compiler.

Comment: I think the biggest performance issues with `containers` follow from two major issues: immutable data and non-strict semantics.  Implementing data structures in C isn't going to help in either case.  To be clear, it's not that these are necessarily incompatible with high performance code, but there are some difficult issues and open research problems.

Comment: I've found that in C, crucial data structures such as strings, structs, arrays etc are implemented in pure C. Wouldn't it be more efficient to implement them in Assembly? I know gcc is good, but it can't compete with optimised assembly code.

Comment: @AntalS-Z Luckily we don't need to go to even the lengths Don did these days - his starting pieces of code perform equivalently when using GHC 7.4+ with LLVM (and is a consistent ~1.5% slower when using the NCG backend).

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson: That's awesome!  I've never written anything which had to be efficient, so I haven't looked into it—I just recalled seeing that post many moons ago.  I will reiterate and refine: GHC is an *incredibly* remarkable compiler.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an interesting question, but I'm not sure that anyone is going to be able to offer any conclusive answer one way or the other (aside from designing and building an extensive test suite and generating a huge pile of numbers).

The *assumption* behind this question appears to be "C is always fast, Haskell is always slow, so wouldn't it be better to write the code in C rather than Haskell?" I'm not sure this assumption is factually accurate. (In my limited experience, it's not that Haskell *is* slow, it's that Haskell *can be* slow - or very fast - and it's awkward to *predict* what kind of speed you're going to get.)

Calling C via the FFI has an overhead. Haskell data structures are handled by the garbage collector; memory used via C has to be manually managed. You're looking at quite a bit of effort here, possibly for not as much benefit as you might think.

C data structures tend to be more efficient because of mutability. Most people don't want to work with mutable data structures in Haskell. (In some sense, it negates all the benefits of using Haskell in the first place, so why bother?) If you use immutable data structures in C, you might even find it goes slower than Haskell. (E.g., I'm told C is quite slow at dynamic memory allocation, which would be a problem for persistent data structures. The alternative is to *copy* stuff all over the place, which also isn't going to be fast.)

On top of that, GHC does clever optimisations like deforestation, which can sometimes result in containers *completely disappearing* at runtime. The C compiler could *never* do such a thing. And Haskell, being a lazy language, can sometimes completely *skip* work that you've asked it to do; that wouldn't work if containers were implemented in C.

In summary, it "looks like" implementing this stuff in C should "obviously" be far faster. In reality, I suspect the answer isn't nearly so clear-cut.

Answer (score 5):

GHC's runtime is optimized for allocating immutable structures efficiently. It typically will beat the C runtime (malloc) at this task. As a result, C is mostly used to optimize algorithms, not data structures. An exception is either very low level data structures, or highly tuned mutable structures.

Answer (score 4):

First, `Data.Map` is not a usual imperative map, but a so called persistent map. It should support efficient keeping of multiple versions of itself. C is not well suited for this type of data structures - for example, classical C-style memory management is not possible.

Second, GHC heap layout is quite complex, especially in this case of working with `Ord a` dictionaries for comparison. So interfacing with old good C is not  straightforward, and costs of interfacing can overrun the advantage of supposedly better code generation.

Implementing `Data.Map` in C is possible, but chances are little that it will help because of all this bookkeeping. You can try and let us know if it is any faster :) As you can see, it has not been done because the community is pretty sure that nothing can be done.